# CSS: How to style last grid row of a dynamic number of items?

Tags: css, css-grid

I have my first row as `22px` and using `grid-auto-rows` to make the subsequent rows `70px`.  Is there a way to make the last row also `22px` without using template since I won't know how many `div`'s are in it at the time?

```css
.cont {
  background: grey;
  height: 600px;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 22px;
  grid-auto-rows: 70px;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-gap: 3px;
}
.cont div {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="cont">
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you will always have 3 columns keep the template row auto and define the height on the elements. All should have `70px` except the first 3 and the last 3 under certain conditions.

```css
.cont {
  background: grey;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-gap: 3px;
  margin:10px;
}
.cont div {
  background: red;
  height:70px;
}

.cont div:nth-child(1), /* 1st */
.cont div:nth-child(2), /* 2nd */
.cont div:nth-child(3), /* 3rd */
.cont div:nth-last-child(1), /* last one */
.cont div:nth-last-child(2):not(:nth-child(3n + 3)), /* before the last if not the last one of a row*/
.cont div:nth-last-child(3):nth-child(3n + 1){ /* before the two last only if the fisrt one of a row*/
  height:22px;
}
```

```html
<div class="cont">
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
</div>

<div class="cont">
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
</div>

<div class="cont">
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you know how many columns your layout is going to have (in my example, it has 3 like yours), you can use the `:nth-child()` and `:last-child()` psuedo-class CSS selectors and do something like this:

```
.cont > div:nth-child(3n+1):nth-last-child(-n+3),
.cont > div:nth-child(3n+1):nth-last-child(-n+3) ~ div {
   height:22px;
}
```

This CSS will always target the individual divs in the last row of your 3 column grid.

Good article on this technique here: https://keithclark.co.uk/articles/targeting-first-and-last-rows-in-css-grid-layouts/